# Radius of convergence of $(1+x)^p$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Problem: Show that $(1+x)^p$ converges everywhere for $p \in \mathbb{N}$, and for $|x| < 1$ otherwise.

My work:
I think that if $p \in \mathbb{N}$ then the Taylor series will just be a polynomial equal to the function so will converge everywhere.

To work out the radius of convergence, consider the $n$-th and $n+1$-th terms, given by $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$.

$A_n = \frac {p(p-1) \cdots (p-n+1)}{n!} x^n$

$A_{n+1} = \frac {p(p-1) \cdots (p-n+2)}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1}$

So $\frac {|A_{n+1}|}{|A_n|} = \frac {|x|} {n(p-n+2)}$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = 0$ therefore the Taylor series will converge everywhere.

How does this proof work for $p \not \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presumably asking about the convergence of the *Maclaurin series* for $(1+x)^p$.

Your argument for non-negative integers $p$ is correct. The series is a polynomial. That's all that needs to be said. Suppose now that $p$ is **not** a non-negative integer.

The Ratio Test was not applied in quite the right way. The coefficient $a_n$ of $x^n$ is given by
$$a_n=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-n+1)}{n!},$$
and therefore 
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-n)}{(n+1)!}.$$
Thus the absolute value of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is
$$\frac{|p-n|}{n+1}.$$
This has limit $1$ as $n\to\infty$. So we have divergence if $|x|\gt 1$ and convergence if $|x|\lt 1$.

**Remark:** Note that we have not dealt with $x=\pm 1$. It is not clear from the wording of the problem whether we are expected to. But in fact if $p$ is not a non-negative integer, then the Maclaurin series of $(1+x)^p$ does not converge at $x=\pm 1$. One can show this by showing that the terms do not approach $0$.